# Libre office format and wps and ms office are not correct

Tags: libreoffice, microsoft-office, wps-office

Hi I created a docx in Libre and opening it in wps office showed wrong spacing, and arrows of flow chart are not aligned correctly. And opening it in ms office of another pc also showed same problem. All are in correct format with libre. When i give a soft copy of docx to window users, this problem makes my document unacceptable with theirs. (Pdf is not allowed to give) How can i fix it. Thanks trillions

Comment: If you create the file using a different format, like .odt, does the same problem occur?

Comment: Relevant: The Free Software Foundation Europe's [opinion on .docx](https://fsfe.org/activities/os/msooxml-interoperability.en.html) (OOXML). Bottom line: Some folks recommend avoiding the .docx format

Comment: @KUK do you still have this problem? Can you upload a .docx file which shows the problem so we can reproduce the problem on our PCs and eventually fill a bug report? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Google Docs web app does a better job of preserving the original formatting of an .odt document than LibreOffice Writer does when converting it from .odt to .docx format. Google Docs can also edit .docx documents natively in case you want to make any revisions in the document before downloading it. As you can see in the screenshot the document that I imported to Google Drive contains a spelling error that can be corrected in Google Docs before downloading the document.

1. Save the document in LibreOffice Writer so that it looks right in the default .odt format.
2. Visit your Google Drive webpage.
3. Import the .odt document to Google Drive.
4. Right-click the .odt document you imported and select *Open with* -> *Google Docs*.
5. In Google Docs select *File* -> *Download* -> *Microsoft Word (.docx)* which is marked by a red arrow in the below screenshot.

   [image: Google Docs]

Answer (score 0):

You could fix this by saving your file in the `.odt` format and asking your recipients to also use LibreOffice to edit the file. An alternative option, agreeing on using Microsoft Office, is less feasible because Microsoft Office is not available on linux. In addition, Microssoft Office is not Free Software, and such agreement would force users to agree to a very restrictive user licence.

Alternatively, change your approach. Text formatting is not a big issue when exchanging between different word processors. However,  expecting to seamlessly exchange graphics in a word processor is an unrealistic expectation. Instead of creating your flow chart in the word processor, create it in a graphics application and embed the graphic in the text document. If the graphic needs to be edited by both parties, then exchanging a graphic created in Impress with Powerpoint will in most circumstances work remarkably well.

Each software has its specific internal workings, which can be quite different. Seamless translation to another file format so that it is seamlessly transferred to another application is fundamentally impossible. So moderate your expectations if you need to go that route. Neither LibreOffice nor MS Office is to blame for that.